# Making element inside founadtion column occupy full width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I need to position the img inside foundation column like this.

[image: The look I need]

My code

```
                <div class="row"> 
                    <img src="/img/profile.jpg"  width="170">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">

                    </div>
                    <div class="large-8 columns">
                        <h3>Jaime Lannister</h3>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

This code positions the img properly but when I put the  tag outside the column the other elements are facing some alignment problems.

If the  tag is put inside column class, this is what I get

[image]

The code

```
<div class="row"> 
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        <img src="/img/profile.jpg"  width="170">
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-8 columns">
                        <h3>Jaime Lannister</h3>
                    </div>
               </div>
```

You can see the image moves slightly right leaving a gap on the left.

On inspecting in chrome,this is what I get

[image]

I tried changing the margin and padding,but nothing helped. Any idea what is the underlying problem?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Its the foundation 5 css

Comment: Please set up a jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

Just add margin-left:0 to row and padding-left:0 to columns

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the class called `collapse` on the row div like `<div class="row collapse">`

this will remove all padding in the children columns. this way you don't mess with the grid structure if you want your site to be responsive!